# Where do you whitelist your domain on Facebook for video embeds?

Tags: facebook

Do you still need to get your domain whitelisted by Facebook to allow embedding of your own Flash videos into feeds?

If so, where do you go to do so?

The old page was: http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=video_embed_whitelist

This, however, now redirects and I'm unable to find any information on this at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to whitelist your domain for videos anymore. You can utilize opengraph and og:video tags to share videos on the user/page walls. more info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

scroll to og:video

hope this helps

Comment: So you don't need any sort of whitelisting at all, you just use the code as normal and it will work? That is awesome!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the flash attachments to display something other than a video? I notice BandPage show a music player.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use Flash to do whatever inside there.. as far as I can think there's no functional difference between video and audio in a Flash component right? So it should be fine!