# How to do a Facebook Video Embed Whitelist Request?

Tags: facebook, video, whitelist

I need to post a swf on user wall and it is able to play inside the wall.

I searched the solution for few days and understand that I need to apply a facebook video embed whitelist request in order to do it. However the old request form link doesnt work (http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=video_embed_whitelist).

Anyone can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do you whitelist your domain on Facebook for video embeds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518833/where-do-you-whitelist-your-domain-on-facebook-for-video-embeds)

Answer (score 1):

If you try writing something in the Facebook pop-up that comes up and then publish it to feed, the video would play there on the wall itself when the thumbnail is clicked.

If the feed doesn't have a message, the thumbnail becomes a direct link to the SWF itself and opens up in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to apply for any whitelist request for this.   Any feed story can contain an SWF in it.  Please see the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for information about what elements you can post within a feed story.  One parameter that you can use is the `source` parameter.  
Taken from the documentation :

> **source:**
>   The URL of a media file (e.g., a SWF or video file) attached
>   to this post. If both source and picture are specified, only source is
>   used.

so... for example - you could make a call with these parameters :

```
 var obj = {
   method: 'feed',
   link: 'http://your_site.com/',
   source: 'http://your_site.com/your_swf_movie.swf',
   name: 'Publish SWF in feed!',
   caption: 'SWF's are cool',
   description: 'Here is an SWF file!.'
 };
 FB.ui(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. Actually I run the same code as your but I cant play it directly in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is in the white list, the swf may play directly on the wall, otherwise it will pop up a new window to play the swf.

Comment: Exactly. I am still checking how to do a white list request.